# CSS keyframe animation with changing background-size does not work on mobile device

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-animations

first of all this is my first stackoverflow post, so I will do my best in writing my problem precisely as possible.

### Background info

I am implementing a simple visualized demo of the Q-learning algorithm using Javascript, Vue.js, and SCSS. The demo can be seen here: https://codepen.io/gkevinb/pen/mvYwWK

By pressing the explore button the robot explores the area and will eventually learn where the reward can be found.
If the robot steps on the black tile, it falls in the hole. If the robot falls press explore again to start exploring again.

### Problem

My problem is that the robot falling in the hole animation does not work on mobile devices. However, for example, when the robot reaches the reward, that animation works on mobile devices. The mobile devices it does not work on include Iphone 6s and Ipad, and I am accessing it through Safari.

```
/*
    Animation for robot falling down the hole.
*/
@keyframes falling {
    0% { background-size: 100% 100%; }
    100% { background-size: 0% 0%; }
}

.tile--robot--falling{
    @include tileSize();
    @include backgroundImage("robot-2", "#{$robot_size}");

    background-color: $cliff_color;

    /* Robot falling animation */
    animation-name: falling;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution! The problem is that on mobile there are some issues with the `background-size` property. The best way to work around is instead of changing the size of the background change the size of the entire `div` which holds the background image.

```
/*
    Animation for robot falling down the hole.
*/
@keyframes falling {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%; 
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
        width: 0%;
    }
}

.tile--robot--falling{
    @include tileSize();
    @include backgroundImage("robot-2", "#{$robot_size}");

    background-color: $cliff_color;

    /* Robot falling animation */
    animation-name: falling;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    /* Needed for keeping falling animation in the center */
    background-size: cover;

    /* Turn off Q-value divs for this tile */
    div{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I have updated my Q-Learning Algorithm demo (https://codepen.io/gkevinb/pen/mvYwWK) and the full solution can be found there.